# How to connect to a distant mysql database using asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to connect to a disant mysql database wich is located in another server using Asp.net C#. 
How can i did it ?
Thanks.

Comment: i think its easier to type the same title in google than SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need this code:

```
var myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test;";
var conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

Also you need the public IP of the MySql server and the correct credentials (userid, password and database name).

Comment: as additional info: it's important, that your IP is allowed to connect to the distant mysql-server by the server. Can be a pun not knowing this.

Comment: i'll try it. thanks :)